# For Loop - Do Something Once Loop Hits Certain Number PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm working on a project for a real estate website. I have a function that uses a for loop to grab a row of data from the database for each available property. Normally this works perfectly but for this particular site the properties are displayed in rows of three. This means that once I have outputted 3 properties, I need to close the current div and open another div to display the next row of 3 properties. So essentially I need the loop to recognize once it hits three rows, echo something like

```
</div><div class="new div">
```

Then pick back up where it left off. My for loop currently looks like this:

```
function showFeaturedHomes() {
    $fetcher = $this->startDataFetch();
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < 30; $idx++)
    {   
        $row = $fetcher->fetch_assoc();
        if (!$row)
            break;
        $retVal .= $this->showBlock($row);
    }
    return ($retVal);
```

I've tried using the modulus operator(%) to detect once it hits a multiple of 3 and while it seems like it works, it's outputting the closing and opening divs BEFORE it does anything else, so I still end up in the same situation.

I hope I've been clear enough about what I'm trying to do, but if not please feel free to ask me for more info. Your help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `$idx > 0 && $idx % 3 == 0`?

Comment: This could be done much easier with CSS, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Hey @Fabricator that's essentially what I was trying before but unfortunately it outputs the closing div tag and opens the new div before it outputs anything else, then just spits out the data as normal. It doesn't do it every third property like I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz, I'm aware that this can be done in CSS, but unfortunately I can't do it that way with this particular site without having to spend 5 hours re-styling the rest of the site as well. This is an existing website, I just have to make it work with our IDX feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showFeaturedHomes() {
    echo '<div class="new div">'; // !!!
    $fetcher = $this->startDataFetch();
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < 30; $idx++)
    {
        if ($idx != 0 && $idx % 3 == 0) echo '</div><div class="new div">'; // !!!
        $row = $fetcher->fetch_assoc();
        if (!$row)
            break;
        $retVal .= $this->showBlock($row);
    }
    echo '</div>'; // !!!
    return ($retVal);
}
```

I dont know if you are returning values through echo and what does showBlock do, but the idea is clear here :). You were close with modulo! Best regards!

Comment: Hey Jacek, that is almost the exact code that I tested earlier and unfortunately I got the same result. However, you brought my attention to the fact that I was echoing the closing div before the showBlock function, which essentially just formats the data that is pulled from the database into html that can then be outputted on the site. Rather than echo I just did retVal .= </div><div class="new div"> and it worked perfectly, lol. It's always the silliest things that I get hung up on, I swear! Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: No problem! As I said: "I dont know if you are returning values through echo and what does showBlock do". Maybe this was the key :). Best regards, and thx for accept!